# How to get Nexus Mod Manager working on Wine?

Tags: xorg, wine, xserver

I'm trying to get Nexus Mod Manager (Beta yet) working on wine, but after the configuration of NMM it crashes with an error.

During the startup it spams a lot of terminal stuff and at the end I find this error:

```
###!!! ABORT: Main-thread-only object used off the main thread: file /build/wine-mozilla-1.8/xpcom/base/nsCycleCollector.cpp, line 1166
###!!! ABORT: Main-thread-only object used off the main thread: file /build/wine-mozilla-1.8/xpcom/base/nsCycleCollector.cpp, line 1166
Maximum number of clients reachederr:winediag:x11drv_init_thread_data x11drv: Can't open display: :0. Please ensure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running wine as root?

Comment: I'm not trying to be a downer, I just wanted to make sure you know - all recent reports on the WineHQ say that the [Nexus Mod Manager](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13777) is garbage with wine.

Comment: Yes, it is rated garbage, but it has gotten a lot better with a couple of latest releases. It actually starts and lets you choose game folders, but it still doesn't run. It looks like the prefix requires just a little bit more tweaking to achieve the bronze rating.