# Does Nexus Mod Manager work with ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

Is there a way to get it to work or does it work with it already? Do i need a specific version?

Answer (score 0):

"A tool for managing, downloading, and installing mods for many of Bethesda's games." in case anyone wonders.

Nope. There is no native client and even [Wine HQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13777) shows a garbage rating or gold

- 2012 topic: [How to get Nexus Mod Manager working on Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229664/how-to-get-nexus-mod-manager-working-on-wine) says: no. Though [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28763) has a working beta on 12.04 there are 2 problems here: beta so limited useable (and 2012 3 years ago), and 12.04.
- 2013 [topic on nexusmods](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/1001171-nexus-mod-manager-on-wine/) says: no.